# MJPG-STREAMER makes my wifi crashed

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

I've got a tricky problem on my RPI3 and its raspicam.
The RPI3 in under Ubuntu 16.04.2 but the problem appears also with Raspban Pixel last version.
I've installed mjpg-streamer with its patch.
I've defined the port 10088 to display the image of the raspicam on a web page.
On my router, I've redirected this port to the local IP of my RPI3's.
The display of the raspicam's image is done through the web page :10088/index.html.
The streaming page is :10088/stream.html.

It works on my laptop but as soon as I display it on my smartphone, it crashes the RPI3's wifi : I cannot do any ping.

In kern.log, I've got the following error message :

```
Jul 7 18:41:49 pat-RPI3 kernel: [ 247.849040] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_hostmail: Unknown mailbox data content: 0x40012
Jul 7 18:41:53 pat-RPI3 kernel: [ 251.027917] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
Jul 7 18:41:55 pat-RPI3 kernel: [ 253.027954] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
Jul 7 18:41:55 pat-RPI3 kernel: [ 253.027977] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_get_station: GET STA INFO failed, -52
Jul 7 18:41:57 pat-RPI3 kernel: [ 255.027962] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
```

Someone knows what happened ? I'me stucked in my project due to this error...
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to encounter the [issue 1342](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1342) which people discuss since March 2016.

Currently it seems to be a firmware issue of the wifi driver which can only be fixed by the company, which is aware and working on it.
Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Workarounds include using USB wifi dongles or cables as discussed in this issue.

Another description is found at [Raspberry Pi builtin WiFi keeps crashing](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=196018).